# TableView not reloading when data is inserted into source from different source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a ChatViewController where I send and receive messages and store the messages as a NSMutableDictionary in an NSArray.

```
NSMutableArray *messages; //in header file

- (void)addMessage:(NSString *)receivedMessage :(NSString *) sender
{
    [self reloadDataInTableView:receivedMessage :sender];
}

- (void)reloadDataInTableView:(NSString *)message :(NSString*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Text: %@ Sender: %@", message, sender);
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [m setObject:message forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:sender forKey:@"sender"];
    [messages addObject:m];
    [self.tView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d", [messages count]);
}
```

When I am calling 'addMessage' from AppDelegate, both the strings are passed but it cannot add it to the 'messages' because the 'Number of rows' always is zero. But when I am storing it from that class itself then the messages are getting stored and row count increases.

As a result, it only shows the messages from the ChatViewController but not the messages sent from the AppDelegate. I hope I was able to explain the problem properly.

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary *s = (NSMutableDictionary *) [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [s objectForKey:@"msg"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [s objectForKey:@"sender"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [messages count];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}
```

Yes, I have initialized the messages array in viewDidLoad. But the problem is when I am trying to insert into the messages array from the AppDelegate the count is not increasing. In fact, it always shows zero. But when I insert from the ViewController itself, it maintains the count. Here is the AppDelegate code:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                                 xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                       managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

        NSString *messageBody = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSString *displayName = [user jidStr];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {
            ChatViewController *cvc = [[ChatViewController alloc] init];
            [cvc reloadDataInTableView:messageBody :displayName];
        }
        else
        {
            // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,messageBody];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is you NSMutableArray initialised?

Comment: Yea, where do you initialise the array `messages`?

Comment: how you sending from AppDelegate? Give that code.

Comment: definetely messages is not initialised

Comment: No, messages must be initialised, because it shows when he tries from the viewController itself. The problem is the reference to it from appDelegate - I guess he's talking to different instances, alloc/initing new ones. How do you keep your reference to the chatViewController in AppDelegate?

Comment: Added the AppDelegate code.

Comment: @Jyotsika have u find answer pls help me.... i m also making chat app with xmpp framework and i m facing same problem and hoe to send image,video and audio file

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
ChatViewController *cvc = [[ChatViewController alloc] init];
[cvc reloadDataInTableView:messageBody :displayName];
```

in your app delegate, you are instantiating a new `ChatViewController`. Even if the `messages` array was initialised in the init method (which it isn't, as you said it is initialised in the `viewDidLoad` method), this new instance of the `ChatViewController` is discarded at the end of your `xmppStream:didReceiveMessage:` method and is definitely not the same that is showing on screen. 
You need to keep a reference to the proper instance of `ChatViewController` in your app delegate and use that instead of instantiating a new one...

If you want some more specific advice on how to approach this problem, you'll need to give us more detail about your whole project's architecture (using storyboard? is there a navigation controller? tab controller? how does the chatviewcontroller relate to other view controllers? etc. etc.).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? I am still not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Check my edit, i need more details about your whole project architecture in order to give you more specific advice on how to solve the problem!

Comment: I am trying to make a chat client based on the following XMPP framework: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP

Comment: Yea, i get that, but the information i need is: are you using storyboards? Is ChatViewController your only view controller? Is it embedded in a navigation controller? or maybe in a tab bar? Is it the first view controller when you open the app? Do you reach it through some combination of segues? that is the kind of information i would need!

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in `viewdidload`

Comment: I have added the edit. Btw, I was already initializing the array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
- (void)reloadDataInTableView:(NSString *)message :(NSString*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Text: %@ Sender: %@", message, sender);
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [m setObject:message forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:sender forKey:@"sender"];
    if (!messages)
    {
        messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [messages addObject:m];
    [self.tView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d", [messages count]);
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to lazy initialise properties from the getter, not from a random method.